# mldivide() code line crushing the laptop

Tags: matlab

I am not sure if this is the correct place for this post. Kindly correct me is if it is not.

I am working on a home assignment and I have the following code line:

```
X = H \ [ Xp(:) Yp(:) ones(wp*hp,1) ]';
```

Almost every time I hit this line my laptop crushes .Now, when I say crush I mean screen keyboard and mouse freezes and nothing short of a power cycle (long power button press) helps.

This is in general a computer vision code and when working with smaller images I have no problem so I am guessing it has something to do eith the size of the images.

I have no idea as to how to address this issue. can anyone help as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the operation is creating a matrix that takes more memory than you actually have available.  Matlab will then use virtual memory, which will cause serious slowdowns like you're seeing.  If you let it run long enough, it might succeed... or it might throw an error.

You can type `help memory` to see available memory, and try to free up more.  Or, you can wrap this operation in a function that checks the size of the inputs and gives an error if they are bigger than a certain size.